# piping the output of gulp to a variable

Tags: gulp

I'm using the [gulp-run](https://github.com/cbarrick/gulp-run) plugin to  get the git hash using the following code:

```
run('git log -1 --pretty=format:%H').exec();
```

I can add a pipe to save the output to a file, like so:

```
run('git log -1 --pretty=format:%H').exec().pipe(gulp.dest('some/dir'));
```

From there, I can read in the contents of the file using readFile() to get the git hash.

Is there a way for me to skip this step, and get the output of gulp-run into a variable directly?

Answer (score 0):

Two comments:

I would recommend

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

Instead of `git log -1 --pretty=format:%H`

And you can easily do this with https://github.com/mgutz/execSync, gulp-run is not necessary.

```
var sh = require('execSync');
var revision = sh.run('git rev-parse HEAD');
console.log(revision); // => 93004330f14fd502e1568a0c2c1a645eae269e1b
```